# Want to redirect all old urls to new domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i want to do redirect 301 for all old urls to new domain, i have tried to do the following :

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
```

but this redirect only the homepage to the new url,and i don't want to write all the pages this way ( as i have so many pages )

also i tried that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

can i do something like that ?

```
Redirect 301 /(.*) http://www.example.com/(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with below code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.knowarth.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, tried that but this redirect only the home page .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: still the same, i want to redirect all the pages not the home page only